# Adding Object element to HTML it opens up many iFrames

Tags: html, svg, frontend

Why when I am importing my SVG image using `object` element (tag) it opens many iFrames and browser gets stuck loading all those infinite numbers of iframes?

**HTML file**

```
    <div class="logo">
      <object class="svg-logo" data="@/assets/logo.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100px">
        <img src="@/assets/logo.svg" alt="logo">
      </object>
    </div>
```

**svg file**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <ellipse class='circle' ry="75" rx="75" id="circle" cy="100" cx="188" fill="#c1f2f2" />
        <text class='fly' font-weight="normal" transform="matrix(4.023622035980225,0,0,4.023622035980225,-455.0551164150238,-273.49606197327375) " xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="'League Gothic', sans-serif" font-size="24" y="101.153041" x="118.807313">Fly</text>
        <text class='high' font-weight="bold" transform="matrix(4.181759433437681,0,0,4.181759433437681,-758.603084468008,-252.31998998550193) " xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="start" font-family="'League Gothic', sans-serif" font-size="24" y="92.792345" x="218.011242">High</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the img in <object> tag?

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' as a fallback. Just was playing around with that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessary to wrap SVG into `<object>`. Simply use the .svg as `<img> src`

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="@/assets/logo.svg" alt="logo" with="100">
</div>
```

Or even insert the asset directly into HTML

```html
<div class="logo">
  <svg width="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    ...
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: it works well with as an img but in this case I cannot refer to it via css. I have no control over it but I want to keep it. That's why I am wondering how to use object instead.

Comment: svg is fine, but it's better to have it outside HTML. Code is cleaner

Comment: Then why not use the direct <svg> code? You will be able to access it's elements with JS.